# Python read csv error using external script

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server-2017, external-script

I am very new to external script and python and was trying with very simple code.

Trying to print the data from a csv file.

```
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script=N' 
import pandas as pd
import csv
data=open("C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/Python/Pandas/olympics - Copy.csv")
data=csv.reader(data)
print(data)'
```

But I get below error

```
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "
```

when I run the same code in jupyter notebook this runs fine.

```
import pandas as pd
oo=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/Python/Pandas/olympics - Copy.csv')
oo.head()
```

what am i missing in SQL ? Can anyone please help me with the syntax?
Also, are there any good resources where I can learn more of using python in SQL 2017?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server you are calling when executing sp_execute_external_script (SPEES), where is that installed; on your machine, or?

Don't forget when you execute SPEES it runs from the SQL box, so unless it is on your machine, it won't work. Even if it is on your machine it may not have permissions to the directory your file is in.

If the SQL is installed on your box, I suggest you create a new directory which you five EVERYONE access to and try with that directory.

Comment: this database instance and also SPEES is not in my system. it is a different server . files are in my local system. If it does not work, what would be the solution? copy the file data into the table and then work on that?

Comment: Copy the file to a directory on the machine where SQL Server is, or as you suggest take the data and insert it into a table in the database.